# How to do capacity planning for SharePoint 2013 DMS application?

Tags: document-library, capacity-planning

Customer has given a DMS application to us for development. Now we got info from customer that total 1 million documents to be managed. Size of avg documents not known. My idea is this application can be developed in SharePoint 2013 and we don’t need any other tool like file server etc.

My question is what are the parameters based on which we can decide if we can built the application on SharePoint or we need any other platform to built?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint supported limit for a document library in SharePoint 2013 is **30 million**, with the file size being **2 GB** per file. Just because the customer said 1 million doesn't mean it's all in one library, create some governance and separate the documents into their respective departments if it makes sense.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary

Comment: But if avg file is 2 gb then what will be content db size? can we manage that much big content db size? when should we go for filenet or documentum etc?

Comment: blob offloading to NAS is going to be your only option

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to have a look into [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) where Microsoft has put information regarding various aspects of SharePoint and how this might relate to performance. There are 3 main categories:

- Boundaries: Static limits that cannot be exceeded by design
- Thresholds: Configurable limits that can be exceeded to accommodate
  specific requirements
- Supported limits: Configurable limits that have been set by default
  to a tested value

You actually should get some more information like how many users system will have in general, how many concurrent users you can expect using system at given moment, what is the average size of the document, as this has a lot of implication on storage - amount of databases, using remote blob storage etc. You want to know this upfront, because it might be hard to change.